# Formating phone number in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, phone-number

Im working on a Database that contains phone numbers, trying to add another column which says which country each number is from. I've tried many diffrent versions, and this is the current one.
I keep getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***PycharmProjects/DataTools/datatools.py", line 11, in <module>
    parsed_number = phonenumbers.parse(number, region=None)
  File "***PycharmProjects/DataTools/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py", line 2849, in parse
    raise NumberParseException(NumberParseException.INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE,
phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException: (0) Missing or invalid default region.
```

```
import pandas as pd
import phonenumbers

path = '****'
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='United_List', dtype=str)
# Normelize phone number
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].str.replace(r'[^0-9]+', "", regex=True)
for number in df['Phone']:
    #number = "+" + number
    print(number)
    parsed_number = phonenumbers.parse(number, region=None)
    print(parsed_number)
print(df['Phone'])

# df.to_excel(path, sheet_name="United_List")
```

I don't ask for anyone to solve this issue for me, just pointing me in the right direction would be great so I can improve myself.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have some sample of your phone numbers, please?

Comment: 919845542411
9259008390
9293320729
9485
9545342144
9705993782811
972001203246978614087651337
14088028780
14088340679
14088960433
14123912486
14152009648
14153289316

Answer (score 0):

I just created a dummy data and works just fine until your for loop.

I suggest simply create a new column

```
df['new_phone'] = df[['phonenumber', 'country']].agg('+'.join, axis=1)
```